# Manipulando o que sera exibido no DisplayMember de uma CheckListBox

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

Tenho uma classe Model:

```
  class pessoaModel
  {
    int id;
    DateTime data;
    TimeSpan hora;
    CliModel ID_Cliente = new CliModel ();

    public string Nome 
    {
        get { return nome; }
        set { nome = value; }
    }

    public int ID
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }

    public TimeSpan Hora
    {
        get { return hora; }
        set { hora = value; }
    }


    public DateTime Data
    {
        get { return data; }
        set { data = value; }
    }        

    public CliModel cliModel 
    {
        get { return CliModel ; }
        set { CliModel = value; }
    }
}
```

Que é preenchida através das informações gravadas no banco de dados. 
Eu preciso que meu DisplayMember tenha o Nome + Data + Hora + CliModel.Nome 
E preciso que o ValueMember seja igual ID.

Estou tentando fazer da seguinte forma

```
        chkAtendimento.DataSource = listaAtendimento;
        chkAtendimento.DisplayMember = "Nome" + "Data" + "Hora" + "CliModel.Nome" 
        chkAtendimento.ValueMember = "Id";
```

Porem não aparece as informações que eu coloquei. 
Como eu faço para que as informações apareçam da forma que eu preciso?

Comment: "Gets or sets a string that specifies a property of the objects contained in the list box whose contents you want to display." O display member deve ser uma propriedade do seu dataSource. Se possível, crie uma propriedade com um get { return Nome + Data + Hora + CliModel.Nome };

Comment: Não tem uma forma de concatenar?

Comment: Com o DisplayMember não. Outra possibilidade é criar uma propriedade anônima para representar o DisplayMember.

Comment: como eu faria a criação de uma propriedade anônima para representar o DisplayMember.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se não for definido nenhum valor para a propriedade `DisplayMember` por padrão será exibido o retorno do método `ToString()` que é um metódo que permite a sobrecarga. Com isso você pode colocar em sua classe um código parecido com o seguinte na sua classe `pessoaModel`

```
public override string ToString()
{
  return string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3}", Nome, Data, Hora, CliModel.Nome);
}
```